# Access different Controller Action from another View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Say I have two different controllers i.e. Controller A and Controller B. How can I access Detail Action of Controller A from PartialView of Controller B.
I tried by javascript

```
document.location = '@Url.Action("Detail", "Controller A")' + "/#id=" + id; OR
windows.location = '@Url.Action("Detail",  "Controller A")' + "/#id=" + id;
```

But its not working. is it a valid scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The way you passing `id` if it is a action parameter is wrong, it should be like this -

```
document.location = "@Url.Action("Detail", "Controller A", new {id = "_Id"})".replace("_Id", id);
```